# Prove $g^{t+s}=g^tg^s$ for a flow map

Tags: group-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

> $g^t$ is a flow map related to the vector field $V$ by the following: $$\dot x=V(x),x(0)=x_0\implies\text{unique soln is }x(t)=g^tx_0$$ Prove $$g^0=I,\\ g^{t+s}=g^tg^s,\\g^{-t}=(g^t)^{-1}.$$

I was able to prove the first bit: $g^0 x_0=x(0)=x_0\forall x_0\in\Bbb R^n\implies g^0=I$. 
 Then the second part is where I struggle - I attempted an infinitesimal approximation:
$$\begin{align}g^tg^sx_0&=g^t(x_0+sV(x_0)+o(s))\\
&=x_0+tV(x_0)+sV(x_0)+o(s)\\&=x_0+(t+s)V(x_0)\\&=g^{t+s}x_0\end{align}$$But I am not sure if this is valid for any $t,s$.
The third part can then be easily deduced from the second part and first part.

---

Can someone offer me any hints for how to do the second part (assuming I have done it wrong)?

Comment: Use the uniquness properties of first-order differential equations (with boundary conditions).

Comment: @anomaly I think what you mean is: $$g^{t+s}x_0=g^tg^sx_0\iff x(t+s)=g^s x(t)=?$$ I don't know how to get the RHS into a form without $g$'s. I could define $x_1=x(t)$, and have $$\dot x=V(x),x(0)=x_1\implies\text{unique soln is }x(t)=g^tx_1$$ But I don't see how to use that.

Comment: Consider the function $x_s(t) = x(t + s)$ for fixed $s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $x(0) = x_0$, let $I(x_0) = [0,\alpha)$ be the maximum time interval over which there exists a unique solution $g^tx_0$ to the initial value problem (IVP) you stated. Suppose $s\in I(g^tx_0)$ and consider the function $x(r)$ defined by
$$ x(r) = \begin{cases} g^rx_0 & \ \ \textrm{ if }r\in[0,t], \\ g^{r-t}g^tx_0 & \ \ \textrm{ if }r\in[t,s+t]. \end{cases} $$
One can verify that $x(r)$ is a solution of the IVP on $[0,s+t)$. Hence, $s+t\in I(x_0)$ and the uniqueness of solution gives
$$ g^{s+t}(x_0) = x(s+t) = g^sg^t(x_0). $$